# Correspondence between fractal sets and trees

Tags: trees, fractals, ergodic-theory

In Hillel Furstenberg's series lectures on ergodic theory in fractal geometry, he mentioned his search on finding a one-to-one correspondence between fractal sets and trees, however, I couldn't not find any material online about this. Does anyone have reference on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out M. Gavish's "Measures with Uniform Scaling Scenery" ([google result](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=gavish+%22Uniform+Scaling+Scenery+Report%22&oq=gavish+%22Uniform+Scaling+Scenery+Report%22&gs_l=hp.3...6561.8332.2.8485.3.3.0.0.0.0.103.293.1j2.3.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.c2JZSYTXA-w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.dmg&fp=82fdc25a886fd9a7&biw=1280&bih=669)) and the sources contained therein.

More precisely, read about the CP-Process (of H. Furstenberg) and its relation to trees.